# Detectar si una app está instalada en Android

Tags: java, android

Quisiera detectar si una app está instalada o no en el dispositivo, por ejemplo Google Earth.

Y si está instalada ejecutarla des de la app.

Comment: Su identificador de la tienda es: `com.google.earth` supongo que es su package name interno

Comment: Y si la aplicación solo esta desactivada, como puedo pedir al usuario que lo active, en el caso de facebook, que hay modelos de móviles que lo tienen desactivado nada mas, al usar este código igual te dice que ya esta instalado pero no habré la app por que esta desactivado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Para detectar si esta instalada una aplicacion**, necesitas conocer el paquete, y puedes detectar si esta instalada en el dispositivo por medio de la clase [**PackageManager**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) , este es un metodo que podrias utilizar:

```
private boolean estaInstaladaAplicacion(String nombrePaquete, Context context) {

    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(nombrePaquete, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

y lo puedes usar de esta forma:

```
if(estaInstaladaAplicacion("com.google.earth", getApplicationContext())){
//esta instalada.
}else{
//no esta instalada.

}
```

**Para abrir la aplicacion**, lo puedes realizar mediante un intent al comprobar que tienes instalada la aplicacion por medio del paquete:

```
String nombrePaquete = "com.google.earth";
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(nombrePaquete );

if(intent == null) {
  //No se puede abrir aplicacion.
}
startActivity(intent); //Abre aplicacion.
```

Answer (score 3):

Proba esto:

```
private boolean isPackageInstalled(String packagename, Context context) {
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
try {
    pm.getPackageInfo(packagename, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
    return true;
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    return false;
}
```

}

aca te dejo un ejemplo:

```
public void someMethod() {
// ...

PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
boolean isInstalled = isPackageInstalled("com.somepackage.name", pm);

// ...
```

}