# Como quitar el Toast ERROR: Ad not found

Tags: android

Estoy utilizando el sdk de Appodeal en mi app y al momento de cargar los anuncios me aparece un Toast que dice que no encuentra Flurry, Facebook, Yandex, Unity, Starapp, entre otros que segun tengo entendido son las fuentes de publicidad para mi app pero no entiendo porque me aparecen esos mensajes si ya complete todos los pasos de la integracion del sdk e inclui todas las librerias de ads necesarias. Ademas el Toast me aparece varias veces nombrando cada una de las redes de mediacion que utliza appodeal aunque el anuncio se haya cargado correctamente y creo que ver todos esos mensajes Toast[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] seria muy molesto para los usuarios de mi app [image: este es el Toast que me aparece]

Answer (score 1):

Tu aplicación requiere de otras aplicaciones las cuales no encuentra, te recomiendo trates de implementar un código el cual verifica si están instaladas las aplicaciones en base a su paquete:

```
private boolean estaInstaladaAplicacion(String nombrePaquete, Context context) {

    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(nombrePaquete, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

si no lo estan, realiza un intent para abrir la playstore y sugiere al usuario instalar las aplicaciones requeridas. Puedes ver más información en esta respuesta:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/17030/95