# No se encontró Google Play Service, como puedo solicitar su instalación?

Tags: android, android-studio, geolocalización, google-play-services

Estoy realizando una `app` con `login` de usuario, una vez es logueado tiene una serie de funciones en la siguiente actividad, de las cuales una de ellas es un servicio de `geo-localización`, al momento en que intento utilizar esa `funcion` me devuelve a la pantalla de `login`, y cuando me vuelvo a loguear aparece un cuadro de dialogo que dice algo como

> "No se encontro Google Play Service"

Y si intento usar la función de nuevo me manda de nuevo al `login`, mi pregunta es: ¿Como puedo lograr que al momento del `OnClickListener`, si la `app` no encuentra `Google Play Services` instalado, solicite o pida al usuario que la instale de `play store` para poder utilizar esa función?

Comment: Hola David ¿Haces referencia en tu AndroidManifest.xml  a Play services en un metadata? ¿Tienes definida la dependencía correcta en tu build.gradle? ¿Que sistema operativo es tu dispositivo?

Comment: Hago referencia en el AndroidManifest.xml con `<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />` , Las dependencias en mi buid.gradle `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'` he probado con esa y con `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'` , actualmente estoy probando con Android 5.1, API 22, aunque quisiera que al menos hasta Android 8.0, API 26 funcione normal.

Comment: @Jorgesys Tambien intente con esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/16974/detectar-si-una-app-est%C3%A1-instalada-en-android